# how to give column values as xml element names in Oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle11g

I have two tables. I am trying to join them and prepare an XML by using SQL/XML (SQLX) in oracle. Here the problem is XMLELEMENT function is taking hardcoded values for element name, but I want to have those names as a column data. Is it possible?

```
create table PRODUCTEDIT
(
PRODUCTEDIT_NUM NUMBER(12) primary key,  
API_NAME        VARCHAR2(255)
);

create table PRODUCTEDITPARAMETER
(
PRODUCTEDIT_NUM NUMBER(12) not null,
PARAMETER_SEQ   NUMBER(9) not null,
PARAMETER_VALUE VARCHAR2(4000),
CONSTRAINT fk_producteditparameter
FOREIGN KEY (PRODUCTEDIT_NUM )
REFERENCES PRODUCTEDIT(PRODUCTEDIT_NUM )
);
```

There are 2 records in first table.

```
PRODUCTEDIT_NUM         Api_Name
1                       ModifyProd
2                       CreateProd
```

Records in second table:

```
PRODUCTEDIT_NUM       PARAMETER_SEQ     PARAMETER_VALUE 
1                        1                    10
1                        2                    Data
1                        3                    1
1                        4                    Data1
1                        5                    1
2                        1                    11
2                        2                    Voice
2                        3                    1
```

Now I want to get XMLOUTPUT like below:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<ModifyProd>
    <1>10</1>
    <2>Data</2>
    <3>1</3>
    <4>Data1</4>
    <5>1</5>
</ModifyProd>
<CreateProd>
    <1>11</1>
    <2>Voice</2>
    <3>1</3>    
</CreateProd>
```

In above XML we have XMLELEMENT names (ModifyProd,CreateProd, 1,2 e.t.c) coming from table data.I am not able to achieve that by using SQLXML in oracle.

I tried below, but doesn't seem to be working. XMLELEMENT is not taking the value the way I am passing.

```
SELECT XMLROOT(
      XMLELEMENT(d.api_name,
             (SELECT XMLAGG(
                       XMLELEMENT(e.parameter_seq,e.parameter_value                            
                       )
                     )
              FROM   producteditparameter e
              WHERE  e.productedit_num = d.productedit_num
             ) 

         ),version '1.0', standalone yes
       )

FROM   productedit d
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide more information - table structures, expected output, what you have tried so far and why it isn't right...

Comment: @AlexPoole is right ... we need more details on want you have, what you want ..

Comment: Your XML has a problem, see [XML Elements](http://www.w3schools.com/Xml/xml_elements.asp): *XML Naming Rules **Element names must start with a letter or underscore***. I.e. elements like `<1>10</1>` are not allowed!

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are looking for this:

```
WITH t AS 
    (SELECT 'foo' AS ELEMENT_NAME, 'bar' AS ELEMENT_CONTENT FROM dual)
SELECT XMLELEMENT(EVALNAME ELEMENT_NAME, ELEMENT_CONTENT)
FROM t;

<foo>bar</foo>
```

**Update based on additional input**

Your result is not a well-formed XML. A XML document must have only one single root element. So, either you ask for several XML documents, then you can do this:

```
SELECT 
    XMLELEMENT(
        EVALNAME Api_Name, 
        XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(EVALNAME parameter_seq, e.parameter_value) ORDER BY parameter_seq)
    ) AS xml_result
FROM PRODUCTEDITPARAMETER e
    JOIN PRODUCTEDIT d USING (productedit_num)
GROUP BY productedit_num, Api_Name;

<ModifyProd><1>10</1><2>Data</2><3>1</3><4>Data1</4><5>1</5></ModifyProd>
<CreateProd><1>11</1><2>Voice</2><3>1</3></CreateProd>
```

or if you need a single XML you have to enclose it by another element, e.g.

```
SELECT 
    XMLELEMENT("Products",  
        XMLAGG(
            XMLELEMENT(
                EVALNAME Api_Name, 
                XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(EVALNAME parameter_seq, e.parameter_value) ORDER BY parameter_seq)
            )
        ) 
    ) AS xml_result
FROM PRODUCTEDITPARAMETER e
    JOIN PRODUCTEDIT d USING (productedit_num)
GROUP BY productedit_num, Api_Name;

<Products><ModifyProd><1>10</1><2>Data</2><3>1</3><4>Data1</4><5>1</5></ModifyProd><CreateProd><1>11</1><2>Voice</2><3>1</3></CreateProd></Products>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if I understood what you want:

```
WITH t AS
       (    SELECT LEVEL col1, 'test' || LEVEL col2
              FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10)
SELECT XMLSERIALIZE (DOCUMENT (xmltype (CURSOR (SELECT col1, col2 FROM t))) INDENT SIZE = 0)
  FROM DUAL;
```

Then, you can use a XSD to transform the output as you want.

Hope it helps